# How to zoom in by giving coordinates?

Tags: android

How to zoom in by giving 2 coordinates(2 Locations) ?

Is there API method for android ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API for that. The closest is `zoomToSpan()` on `MapController`. You could compute the center point between your two coordinates, center the map there, and use `zoomToSpan()` to attempt to zoom in/out to make your two locations visible on the map. I have not tried this method, so I do not know how well it works.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got it.

Comment: Actually there are APIs to do that. ItemizedOverlay has getCenter, getLatSpanE6 and getLonSpanE6.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666922/auto-size-zoom-on-google-maps-in-java-depending-android-screen-resolution