# Why does GoogleMap.animateCamera() crash after onGlobalLayout()?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've a problem with a Fragment that embeds the SuportMapFragment from the new Google Maps API. When my fragment is created it fetches some data in an `AsyncTask` beginning in the `onResume` method. While this happens the MapFragment remains off-screen, instead a progress bar is displayed.

When the `AsyncTask` is completed, I register with the `onGlobalLayout` event of the mapView. Then I display the fragment, which results in the map view being shown and layouted. `onGlobalLayout` is triggered and the animation starts.

This worked fine for quite some time, until I started optimizing the operations in the data gathering `AsyncTask` to complete almost instantaneously. Now the app will often crash when started, more often in Release than Debug, which is why I think that I'm dealing with a racing condition here that I'm not aware of.

The exception reads:

> Map size should not be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

For reference: This is the code that seems to cause the crash:

```
// Hide status UI
this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
this.statusTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// Update state
this.uraDataDownloadFinished = true;

// Schedule map translation to occur when layout is complete
final View mapView = this.mapFragment.getView();
if (mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive())
{
    mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @SuppressLint("NewApi") // We check which build version we are using.
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout()
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onGlobalLayout()");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            {
              mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
            else
            {
              mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }

            // here we crash
            this.map.animateCamera(
                    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
                            LatLngBounds.builder()
                                .include(topLeft)
                                .include(topRight)
                                .include(bottomLeft)
                                .include(bottomRight)
                                .build(),
                            0),
                    durationMs,
                    null);
        }
   });
}

// Show map (which will eventually trigger onGlobalLayout)
this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(this.mapFragment).commit();
this.mapFragment.getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure but as you are using AsyncTask is probably that you are trying to get map bounds before map has undergone layout.

You can see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#setting_boundaries), it suggest to use `newLatLngBounds(boundary, width, height, padding)` instead .

Comment: Thanks, that works. Since the map completely fills a layout container, I can use its dimensions instead. However, my question remains. Since I'm waiting for `onGlobalLayout()`, I should not run into this problem, should I?

Comment: No, I don't think so, you have to wait till maps has undergone layout.

Comment: I see, so the `MapView`'s layout is no indication for the map layout. Just out of curiosity: Is there a way to listen to the layout process of the map or is that not possible? I'm not seeing anything obvious looking at the API.

Comment: I never use that, but you can figure it out following this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692579/movecamera-with-cameraupdatefactory-newlatlngbounds-crashes)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one, it works for me:

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
        // Move camera.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 10));
        // Remove listener to prevent position reset on camera move.
        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
    }
});
```