# Determining suitable zoom level based on a set of locations on Google Map Android API v2

Tags: java, android, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to find if there's an algorithm/method out there that can help determine a suitable zoom level for initial display.

For example, given a set of locations Point A,B,C,D and E, how can I determine the correct zoom level that will display all locations on the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for (Location loc : allLocations) {

    LatLng position = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
    builder.include(position);

}

CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), someMarginValue);
map.moveCamera(cu);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! However I get this error: 01-27 23:41:39.820: E/AndroidRuntime(20092): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Map size should not be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.

At the line map.moveCamera(cu). what does this mean?

Comment: Never mind I found the answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692579/movecamera-with-cameraupdatefactory-newlatlngbounds-crashes

Thanks alot!