# how to get current location in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps

Actually my problem is I am not getting current location latitude and longitude I tried so many ways.I know that this question already asked in SO I tried that answers also still I didn't get answer.Please help me
Code:

```
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    Location myLocation = googleMap.getMyLocation();  //Nullpointer exception.........
    LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(),
            myLocation.getLongitude());

    CameraPosition myPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(myLatLng).zoom(17).bearing(90).tilt(30).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(myPosition));
```

Comment: get the answer in Kotlin here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53800632/2201814

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Please check the sample code for the [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker). Using this will solve your problem.

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude())).title("It's Me!"));
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Call this function in `onCreate` function.

**Update:**

The method mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener is now deprecated, you need to use the `FusedLocationProviderClient` now.

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
}
```

To request the last known location, call the getLastLocation() method. The following code snippet illustrates the request and a simple handling of the response:

```
fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                if (location != null) {
                    // Logic to handle location object
                }
            }
        });
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: I am getting map and I am able to show custom markers also.My problem is I am  not getting current location where I am getting null pointer exception

Comment: Try to use `SupportMapFragment` instead of using `MapFragment` more info refer this http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46219/discussion-between-shylendra-and-peter)

Comment: The method mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener is now deprecated, you should check Andrey response now. https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: This is deprecated because mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); takes too much usage of battery which leads to a bad User Experience. Avoid this way and use FusedLocationProviderClient.

Answer (score 21):

I think that better way now is:

```
Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
```

[Documentation. Getting the Last Known Location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, as `OnMyLocationChangeListener` is deprecated: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener

Comment: Actually, the FusedLocationApi is now deprecated. I wrote an answer below that works, and it's basically just borrowing from here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies#FastFix. I would recommend doing this if you just need the location at specified points in time. It's silly to have a location change listener running if you just want to programmatically get the user's location as the asker did

Comment: FusedLocationApi interface was deprecated [2]
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi

Answer (score 12):

```
package com.example.sandeep.googlemapsample;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //Initializing googleApiClient
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
       // googleMapOptions.mapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID)
                    //    .compassEnabled(true);

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng india = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(india).title("Marker in India"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(india));
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    //Getting current location
    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        mMap.clear();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            //Getting longitude and latitude
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            //moving the map to location
            moveMap();
        }
    }

    private void moveMap() {
        /**
         * Creating the latlng object to store lat, long coordinates
         * adding marker to map
         * move the camera with animation
         */
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true)
                .title("Marker in India"));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.v(TAG,"view click event");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        getCurrentLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        // mMap.clear();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "onMarkerDragStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "onMarkerDrag", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        // getting the Co-ordinates
        latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

        //move to current position
        moveMap();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "onMarkerClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to improve it.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't need to retrieve the user's location every time it changes (I have no idea why nearly every solution does that by using a location listener), it's just wasteful to do so. The asker was clearly interested in retrieving the location just once. Now FusedLocationApi is deprecated, so as a replacement for @Andrey's post, you can do:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    // I suppressed the missing-permission warning because this wouldn't be executed in my 
    // case without location services being enabled
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") android.location.Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
    double userLat = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
    double userLong = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
```

This just puts together some scattered information in the docs, [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies#FastFix) being the most important source.

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, you saved my day.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I just changed `this` to `getContext()` because I used your code in a fragment

Answer (score 6):

1. Select google map activity

   [image]
2. you need a Google Maps API key.

   To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:
   https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=48:C7:A8:5B:31:4F:78:F2:38:41:97:F4:70:C3:A0:EB:6A:73:28:88%3Bcom.example.myapplication
3. Paste this Code in MapsActivity.java

> ```
> import android.Manifest;
> import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
> import android.location.Location;
> import android.os.Build;
>
> import android.os.Bundle;
>
> import android.widget.Toast;
>
> import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
> import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
> import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
>
> import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
> import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
> import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
> import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
> import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
> import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
> import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
> import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
> import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
> import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
> import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
> import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
> import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
>
>
>
>   public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implement
>    OnMapReadyCallback,
>    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
>    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
>   LocationListener{
> ```

```
    @private GoogleMap mMap;
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        Location mLastLocation;
        Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;


            //Initialize Google Play Services
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            mLastLocation = location;
            if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
            }

            //Place current location marker
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            //move map camera
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));

            //stop location updates
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

        public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
        public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Asking user if explanation is needed
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                    //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[] {
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        },
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


                } else {
                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[] {
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        },
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
            String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION:
                    {
                        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                        if (grantResults.length > 0 &&
                            grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            // permission was granted. Do the
                            // contacts-related task you need to do.
                            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                                if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                                }
                                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                            }

                        } else {

                            // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                            Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        return;
                    }


            }
        }
    }
```

4. Make sure these permission are written in Manifest file

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

   [image]
5. Add following dependencies

   `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'`

   `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'`

   [image]

Comment: onRequestPermissionsResult is deprecated.  what should be the alternate for this method.

Answer (score 5):

This Code in `MapsActivity` Class works for me :

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

public void centreMapOnLocation(Location location, String title){

    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    mMap.clear();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title(title));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation,12));

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);

            Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            centreMapOnLocation(lastKnownLocation,"Your Location");
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getIntExtra("Place Number",0) == 0 ){

        // Zoom into users location
        locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                centreMapOnLocation(location,"Your Location");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
                Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                centreMapOnLocation(lastKnownLocation,"Your Location");
        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
        }
    }


}


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your current location might not be available immediately, after the map fragment is initialized.

After set

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

you have to wait until you see the blue dot shown on your MapView. Then

```
Location myLocation = googleMap.getMyLocation();
```

myLocation won't be null.

I think you better use the [LocationClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) instead, and implement your own LocationListener.onLocationChanged(Location l)

[Receiving Location Updates](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) will show you how to get current location from LocationClient

Comment: getMyLocation is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

```
Location locaton;

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

            CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11);
            mMap.clear();

            MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

            mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

            mp.title("my position");

            mMap.addMarker(mp);
            mMap.moveCamera(center);
            mMap.animateCamera(zoom);

        }
    });}}
```

Comment: setOnMyLocationChangeListener is deprecated so now what we used for this behavior?

Comment: @ArslanMaqbool, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53851018/2914140: use `OnCamera...Listener`.

Answer (score 3):

`FusedLocationApi` has been `Deprecated` (Why Google always deprecated everything!)

[location: retrieve-current](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current)

Here is the way to get it now:

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void getMyLocation() {
        // create class object
        gps = new GPSTracker(HomeActivity.this);
        // check if GPS enabled
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            Geocoder geocoder;
            List<Address> addresses;
            geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
                Log.e("Location",postalCode+" "+city+" "+address+" "+state+" "+knownName);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

All solution mentioned above using that code which are deprecated now!Here is the new solution

1. Add  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1' dependency in your gradle file
2. Add network permission in your manifest file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

3. Now use this code to get current location

   ```
     FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

     mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                       // GPS location can be null if GPS is switched off
                           currentLat = location.getLatitude();
                           currentLong = location.getLongitude();
                           Toast.makeText(HomeNavigationBarActivtiy.this, "lat " + location.getLatitude() + "\nlong " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               })
               .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               });
   ```

Comment: This solution also requires granting permissions.

Answer (score 2):

From Google Sample `(CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap)` for `kotlin` by `FusedLocationProviderClient` in order to `setOnMyLocationChangeListener` is `deprecated`

at first add `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'` to `dependencies`

next in your `fragment` add these variables

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private var lastKnownLocation: Location? = null
```

next in `onViewCreated` add this

```
    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext())
```

in `onMapReady` call this method

```
private fun getDeviceLocation() {
    /*
     * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
     * cases when a location is not available.
     */
    try {
            val locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
            locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(context as Activity) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                    lastKnownLocation = task.result
                    if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                LatLng(lastKnownLocation!!.latitude,
                                        lastKnownLocation!!.longitude), DEFAULT_ZOOM.toFloat()))
                    }
                } else {
                    logD("Current location is null. Using defaults.")
                    logD("Exception: ${task.exception}")
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(35.6892, 51.3890), 15.toFloat()))
                    mMap.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false
                }
            }
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
        logD("Exception: ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

if `lastKnownLocation` be null you should update it with this method:

```
fun requestLocation(context: Context) {
        val mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        mLocationRequest.interval = 60000
        mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 5000
        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        val mLocationCallback: LocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                for (location in locationResult.locations) {
                    if (location != null && lastKnownLocation == null) {
                        lastKnownLocation = location
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
            .requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null)
    }
```

if you want, you can turn on your location by this

```
mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the permissions to the app manifest

Add one of the following permissions as a child of the  element in your Android manifest. Either the coarse location permission:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp" >
  ...
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  ...
</manifest>
```

Or the fine location permission:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp" >
  ...
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  ...
</manifest>
```

The following code sample checks for permission using the Support library before enabling the My Location layer:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
} else {
    // Show rationale and request permission.
}
The following sample handles the result of the permission request by implementing the ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback from the Support library:

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (permissions.length == 1 &&
          permissions[0] == Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION &&
          grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
      // Permission was denied. Display an error message.
    }
}
```

This example provides current location update using GPS provider. Entire Android app code is as follows,

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
TextView txtLat;
String lat;
String provider;
protected String latitude,longitude; 
protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
Log.d("Latitude","disable");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
Log.d("Latitude","enable");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
Log.d("Latitude","status");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple steps to get current location on google map:**

1 - create map activity so in onMap ready method you create LocationManager and LocationListener

2 - in onMap ready also you check for android version and user permission ==> if there is a permission give location update OR ask the user for permission

3 - in the main class check for result of permission (onRequestPermissionsResult) ==> if the condition is true so give location update

4 - in (onLocationChanged) method we create LatLng variable and get the coordinates from location then from mMap we (addMarker and moveCamera) for that variable we've just created, this gives us location when the user moves so we still need to create new LatLng in onMap ready  to have user's location when the App starts ==>inside condition if there is permission (lastKnownLocation).

**NOTE:**

1) Do Not forget to ask for permissions (Location and Internet) in Manifest

2) Do Not forget to have Map key from google APIs

3) We used (mMap.clear) to avoid repeating the marker each time we (run the app or update location)

**Coding Part**:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        locationManager  = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                mMap.clear();

                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Marker"));

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));

                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, userLocation.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }


        };

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 ){

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        }else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

            Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());

            mMap.clear();

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Marker"));

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));

            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, userLocation.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

        }


    }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//check this condition if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 )
```

In some android studio it does not work while Whole code is working, so replace this line by this:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
```

& my project is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
         import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient client;
    double latit;
    double longi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    }
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;



        try {
            setupMap();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
 client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    Activity#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        client.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                        if (location != null) {

                            //    local=findViewById(R.id.tv5);

                            double la=location.getLatitude();
                            double lo=location.getLongitude();

                            LatLng curre=new LatLng(la,lo);
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(curre,18));

                        }
                    }
                });



    }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain this answer so that it's not just a big block of code?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use `FusedLocationApi` instead of `OnMyLocationChangeListener`? You need to initialize GoogleApiClient object and use `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()` method to register location change listener. It is important to note, that don't forget to remove the registered listener and disconnect `GoogleApiClient`.

```
private LocationRequest  mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient  mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationListener mLocationListener;

private void initGoogleApiClient(Context context)
{
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context).addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks()
    {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
        {
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);

            setLocationListener();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
        {
            Log.i("LOG_TAG", "onConnectionSuspended");
        }
    }).build();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

private void setLocationListener()
{
    mLocationListener = new LocationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            String lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            String lon = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            Log.i("LOG_TAG", "Latitude = " + lat + " Longitude = " + lon);
        }
    };

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mLocationListener);
}

private void removeLocationListener()
{
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationListener);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
...
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}
}
```