# Show my current location in the Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, gps

Finally I succeed to display the map,Now,I want to show my current location, I tried by using these code but it didn't work  when I clicked the my location button in the top right corner.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.hp.testmap.MAPS_RECEIVE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.hp.testmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
```

MapsActivity.java

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

       LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

       Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

       String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

       Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

       mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Code for Current Location:

```
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //                                          int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    return;
}
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

if (locationManager == null) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}
if (locationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkProviderEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (isGPSEnabled) {
        location = getLastLocationByProvider(locationManager, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, getApplicationContext());
    } else if (isNetworkProviderEnabled) {
        location = getLastLocationByProvider(locationManager, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, getApplicationContext());
    }
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    } else {
        if (isNetworkProviderEnabled) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100000, 1, this);
            provider_info = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        } else if (isGPSEnabled) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100000, 1, this);
            provider_info = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        } else {

            alertDialog = Util.showOkDialog(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (Env.currentActivity != null) {
                        if (Env.currentActivity instanceof LocationActivity) {
                            try {
                                gotoSettings();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if (alertDialog != null) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                        alertDialog = null;
                    }

                }
            }, this.getResources().getString(R.string.location_service_validation));

        }

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider_info);
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .title(getFullAddressLine(this));
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));

    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(latitude,
                    longitude)).zoom(15).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private GoogleMap mMap;
```

**Implement this listeners**:

```
LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

**onCreateView or onCreate method**:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

**@Override Methods**:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null)
            onLocationChanged(mLastLocation);
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude())));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(6), 5000, null);
    }
}
```

Hope your task done.

Comment: import latest google-play-service --> 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

Answer (score 2):

```
public void showMap() {

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (map == null) {
        map = mapFragment.getMap();
    }


    // Enable Zoom
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

    //set Map TYPE
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    //enable Current location Button
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 2000, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    latitude= location.getLatitude();
    longitude=location.getLongitude();

    LatLng loc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

     if (marker!=null){
         marker.remove();
     }

    marker=  map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("Sparx IT Solutions"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Gps is turned off!!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Gps is turned on!! ",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following code:

```
//Zoom to the current location
public Location getMyLocation() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
    if (location != null) {
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    }

    return location;
}
```

Then call this method insode your onCreate

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Read the following documentation- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#the_my_location_layer

Possible duplicate of - [how to get current location in google map android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403496/how-to-get-current-location-in-google-map-android)