# city name from gps

Tags: android, gps, location, android-gps

I`m Trying to get city name in an application. Just like if the GPS shows New York so the place should set inside an text view as new York and if the GPS shows location as India so the text view should show as India

Comment: Have a look at Geocoder: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html Of course, first you will need the geoposition.

Comment: It does not shows any code

Comment: visit this https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); 

String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
```

Comment: Just i need to add this code? or something else i need to add?

Comment: first of all get lat long from GPS then add this code

Comment: because you need lat long first

Comment: follow this link to get lat long http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622586/show-my-current-location-in-the-google-map/36623078#36623078

Comment: you havent understand my question.. i dont want to open map... Just like an fake gps we can set fake location through an app.. so if we set india from that app so that in my application if i search for it then it should automatically fetch india from that