# want current location latitude and longitude in android target api 23

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new in android and I want to fetch the current latitude and longitude. And i am using target api 23 and i am using location manager and i have also added 
check of permissions in my activity class also but i am not able to fetch the current location latitude and longitude,please help me and thanks in advance
For the complete code here is the link https://github.com/akashmalla07/Google

Here is the code of GPSTracker.java

```
 public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(

                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,

                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,

                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                Log.d("Network", "Network");

                if (locationManager != null) {

                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation
                      (LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (location != null) {

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();

                        longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    }

                }


 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 

  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
   PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
  ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    return location ;

                }

            }

            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation
                            (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to 
                          settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new 
             DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new 
        Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 
       DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: The problems of your code are discussed in detail [in this blog post](http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/).

Answer (score 0):

You can start by checking the documentation [Making Your App Location-Aware](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html). It says here how to use the [Google Play services location APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary.html) in your app to get the current location, get periodic location updates, and look up addresses. The class includes sample apps and code snippets that you can use as a starting point for adding location awareness to your app.

The Google Play services location APIs is also preferred over the Android framework location APIs as a way of adding location awareness to your app.

Check and explore more the link above to know more information like how to retrieve the last known location of an Android device, how to detect and apply system settings for location features, how to request and receive periodic location updates and etc.

Check also this related SO question for more information and sample code:

- [How to get the current location latitude and longitude in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519198/how-to-get-the-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-android)
- [how to get current location in google map android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403496/how-to-get-current-location-in-google-map-android)