# How to get current location in map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am trying to implement current location map application and I am loading map in fragment but it takes latitude and longitude value to locate the address ..How to implement current location functionality to map...Thanks in advance..

Here is my map fragment..

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment {
MapView mapView;
GoogleMap googleMap;
private WebView contactWebView;
public ContactFragment() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);
    getActivity().setTitle("Contact Us");
    contactWebView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.contact_us);
    contactWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
        contactWebView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    contactWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    AssetManager mgr = getContext().getAssets();
    String filename = null;
    try {
        filename = "contact.html";
        System.out.println("filename : " + filename);
        InputStream in = mgr.open(filename, AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER);
        String sHTML = StreamToString(in);
        in.close();
        contactWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, sHTML, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        //singleContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(sHTML));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (mapView != null) {
        googleMap = mapView.getMap();
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker))
                .anchor(0.5f, 1.0f)
                .position(new LatLng( 12.895960, 77.559921)));
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
            LatLng position = new LatLng(12.895960, 77.559921);
            CameraUpdate updatePosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position);

            googleMap.moveCamera(updatePosition);
            //googleMap.animateCamera(updatePosition);

            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position,16));
            return view;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        //            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
 //            builder.include(new LatLng(12.8909537, 77.5594254));
 //            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        int padding = 0;
        LatLng position = new LatLng(12.895960, 77.559921);
        CameraUpdate updatePosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position);
        CameraUpdate updateZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(8);
        googleMap.moveCamera(updatePosition);
        googleMap.animateCamera(updateZoom);



    }
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}
public static String StreamToString(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    if(in == null) {
        return "";
    }
    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    try {
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        int n;
        while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    } finally {
    }
    return writer.toString();
}



}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Google Maps API V2 Zoom to Current Location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425141/android-google-maps-api-v2-zoom-to-current-location)

Comment: RTFM [Google Maps APIs | Location Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        if (mMap != null) {


         mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude())).title("It's Me!"));
       }
      });

        }
    }
```

Comment: it is asking permission check error at mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Comment: have you added location permissions in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes i added all permission in manifest file...please send me full altered code of fragment..thank u

Comment: @PankajJadhav are you testing on Android 6.0+?

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question. The provided code is for adding a map marker at the current location, not for adding a button "My Location" which navigates to the current location!

Answer (score 0):

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location) of Google, the location data available to an Android device includes the current location of the device pinpointed using a combination of technologies - the direction and method of movement, and whether the device has moved across a predefined geographical boundary, or geofence.

> Depending upon the needs of your application, you can choose between
>   several ways of working with location data:
>
> - The **My Location layer** provides a simple way to display a device's location on the map. It does not provide data.
> - The **Google Play services Location API** is recommended for all programmatic requests for location data.
> - The [LocationSource](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource)
>     interface allows you to provide a custom location provider.

For more information, just check the documentation it will explain you everything that you need and these tutorials and related SO question.

- [Google Map Tutorial in Android Studio: How to get current location in Android Google Map](http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/android-map-app-showing-current-location-android/)
- [Android Show Current Location on Map using Google Maps API](http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/)
- [how to get current location in google map android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403496/how-to-get-current-location-in-google-map-android)