# How can i get the current position?

Tags: android

I am working on an app that calculate the distance between 2 points but i don't now how to get the current position.I'm using a google maps activity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code:

```
LocationManager service = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false); service.requestLocationUpdates(provider,1000,0,locationListenerGPS); Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider); 
LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
```

Comment: post your code here please

Comment: I suggest you use Google to research the Android Location Services API.

Comment: i use this code but it retun null:

Comment: LocationManager service = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        service.requestLocationUpdates(provider,1000,0,locationListenerGPS);
        Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

Comment: You can refer to this link to find out the answer to your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403496/how-to-get-current-location-in-google-map-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the documentation for this . `LocationManager` is not the best way. Use GooglePlayServices.

Check out the step by step way in the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current)