# Google Map-Android Centering and Zooming?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying focus the map on the marker at a certain zooming ratio. I've looked at a couple posts in stackoverflow and I couldn't see any reason why I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error using
>   newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): Map size can't be 0

Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.  Either wait until layout has occurred or use `newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int)` which allows you to specify the map's dimensions.

The code that I am using is:

```
private void setUpMap(String address) throws IOException {
  Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
  List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
  Address add = list.get(0);
  double Longitude = add.getLongitude();
  double Latitude= add.getLatitude();
  Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude)).title(address));
  LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
  builder.include(m.getPosition());
  LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10));
}
```

I debugged the code, and it is throwing the previous exception on the line

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10));
```

Any suggestion here? thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692579/movecamera-with-cameraupdatefactory-newlatlngbounds-crashes

Comment: @HarshDattani.  This did not answer or solve my problem.. I did everything correct.. but still getting this exception..

Comment: I think the issue maybe related to passing only one location to the LatLngBounds.builder, I would think you need at least two locations for it to provide a size larger than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use just one location from an address, and set the zoom on that one marker, you can use `CameraPosition` instead of `LatLngBounds`.

I just tested this, and it works:

```
private void setUpMap(String address) throws IOException {
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
        Address add = list.get(0);
        double Longitude = add.getLongitude();
        double Latitude= add.getLatitude();
        Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude)).title(address));

        //not needed:
        //LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        //builder.include(m.getPosition());
        //LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10));

        //use CameraPosition instead:
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLng).zoom(14).build();

        //use animateCamera instead of moveCamera:
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
```

Calling the method:

```
try {
    setUpMap("100 Market Street San Francisco CA");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that usually when using `LatLngBounds`, you would initially provide two points that are the Northeast and Southwest corners of the bounds.

Once those two bounds have been set, you can use the `include()` method to [expand the bounds if necessary](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.Builder.html#include(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)).

See Documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views

Comment: Thank you @DanielNugent for the answer, it seems that every time I launch the emulator it crashes (NOT THE APP). I tried to launch it 3 times and still crashes.. maybe there is something happening in the background. Any idea why

Comment: Yes, and I enabled the debugging mode and android studio still couldn't catch my mobile!!

Comment: I have oneplusone, and yes i tried it before and it worked.. Android KitKat

Comment: I will, and let you know.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76685/discussion-between-daniel-nugent-and-riad).

Comment: The emulator fails each time I launch the app and still did not catch my mobile device.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel for your efforts.. yes it's working on my mobile device :)