# Google maps won't load - Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

The current error i'm getting is: ***Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): Map size can't be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view. Either wait until layout has occurred or use newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int) which allows you to specify the map's dimensions.***

I'm going to assume I'm getting this error because the layout has not been loaded yet, how can I rectify this issue within my code?

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private LatLngBounds AUSTRALIA = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-44, 113), new LatLng(-10, 154));


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();


    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }




    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(AUSTRALIA, 0));
    }

}
```

The line: `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(AUSTRALIA, 0));` in the `SetUpMap();` Method. Is causing this issue by the way, and as I'm trying to use google's API V2 documentation do I need to use a callback on Google maps after the map has loaded or a separate method to initialise after a certain time period?

Comment: Please check this question : [moveCamera with CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds crashes][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692579/movecamera-with-cameraupdatefactory-newlatlngbounds-crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your map is not ready.
You can use MapLoadedCallBack;

```
map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onMapLoaded() {
      map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 30));
  }
});
```

and also you can you a prier event to this that is.

```
 map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 30));
  }
});
```

Comment: Okay so where would I change MapLoadedCallBack within my Activity? I tried implementing both solutions but I keep on getting weird errors. For example where does map.SetOnMapLoadedCallback above the method go? Or does that stay in the same spot just above onMapLoaded method?

Comment: I stays in the same spot it just gives callback that is invoked when this map has finished rendering.