# Google maps api how to save data during rotation screen?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm developing the app and I have `MapActivity` where I have a map. I wanted to save data(the last coordinates, zoom) during rotation screen and I tried to do it using this way

```
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // saving the last zoom, coordinates
    double lat = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;
    double lon = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;
    float zoom = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;

    savedInstanceState.putDouble("map_lat", lat);
    savedInstanceState.putDouble("map_lon", lon);
    savedInstanceState.putFloat("map_zoom", zoom);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the last zoom, coordinates
    double lat = savedInstanceState.getDouble("map_lat");
    double lon = savedInstanceState.getDouble("map_lon");
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
    float zoom = savedInstanceState.getFloat("map_zoom", 15);

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
}
```

But this code doesn't work. I get the next error

`2019-02-26 17:41:15.529 20867-20867/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-02-26 17:41:15.529 20867-20867/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
2019-02-26 17:41:15.529 20867-20867/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
2019-02-26 17:41:21.286 20867-20867/com.example.mapsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mapsapp, PID: 20867
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapsapp/com.example.mapsapp.activities.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1702)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.mapsapp.activities.MapActivity.onRestoreInstanceState(MapActivity.java:99)
        at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1108)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1267)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2930)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4921) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1702) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)`

Can you help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the restoring code to onCreate, after the mGoogleMap variable is initialized and remove the onRestoreInstanceState method.

The problem is that your mGoogleMap variable is null when onRestoreInstanceState is called.

Comment: but my mGoogleMap is initialized in onMapReady() where I can't get savedInstanceState

Comment: So simply declare lat, lot and zoom variables outside as a class members, and then use them inside onMapReady() after map is initialized.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work again. What's wrong with this?

Comment: I've been testing my new code and it works all but my camera don't move to the last place where i was. Why? I tried to add a marker in resetDataOnMap() method and it was set in the last place. Therefore, why don't the camera move to that place?

Comment: Try mGoogleMap.animateCamera. Read also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34117053/1860868

Comment: If my answer was helpful don't forget to accept it :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A new way to fix my problem, why doesn't it work?:

```
 // the last data before rotation the screen
private float mLastZoom = 0;
private LatLng mLastLatLng = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    // restore data after rotation
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        double lat = savedInstanceState.getDouble("map_lat");
        double lon = savedInstanceState.getDouble("map_lon");
        mLastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        mLastZoom = savedInstanceState.getFloat("map_zoom");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // saving the last zoom, coordinates
    double lat = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;
    double lon = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;
    float zoom = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;

    savedInstanceState.putDouble("map_lat", lat);
    savedInstanceState.putDouble("map_lon", lon);
    savedInstanceState.putFloat("map_zoom", zoom);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    resetDataOnMap();
}

 private void resetDataOnMap() {
    if (mLastLatLng != null && mLastZoom != 0) {
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLastLatLng, mLastZoom));
    }
}
```