# OnMapLoadedCallback and OnMapReadyCallback, when to use which?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

While working a ViewHolder of GoogleMap Lite, as part of the row in RecyclerView, I'm looking for callback to set the pins location when the Map is ready. I found both function below.

1. OnMapLoadedCallback : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback?hl=en
2. OnMapReadyCallback : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback

Both also proven working and usable (as shown below). Hence I'm puzzled if they do have any specific different behaviour that should be used at different occasion, or they are indeed similar and could be used interchangably?

The use of OnMapLoadedCallback:

```
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker marker : markers) {
        builder.include(marker.getPosition());
    }

    final CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 0);
    googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    });
```

The use of OnMapReadyCallback:

```
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker marker : markers) {
        builder.include(marker.getPosition());
    }

    final CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 0);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    });
```

Thanks!!

Comment: thanks that you have asked the question, I was looking for the same :)

Answer (score 6):

You can safely use `OnMapReadyCallback` to set your pins. It is called as soon as the map is ready for you to use it.

`OnMapLoadedCallback`, as the docs state, is called

> when the map has finished rendering. This occurs after all tiles
>   required to render the map have been fetched, and all labeling is
>   complete.

eg. the map's content is fully loaded and visible.

This happens later than OnMapReady. I don't see a reason to wait for that event.

**EDIT:** The call  `googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback` even implies that `OnMapReady` already happened to be able to be called safely (`googleMap != null`).

Comment: Thanks Ascorbin. it definitely good to use the one that is ready sooner. In what scenario would we use OnMapLoadedCallback then?

Comment: @Elye I don't know, perhaps one might show a ProgressBar until the map has fully loaded or hide the map and do some fancy fade in animation when the map is loaded.

Comment: you can face issues if you only rely on onMapReady callback as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692579/movecamera-with-cameraupdatefactory-newlatlngbounds-crashes

Answer (score 2):

As the **Google Documentation says:**

**1. OnMapLoadedCallback :**

> Called when the map has finished rendering. This will only be called
>   once. You must request another callback if you want to be notified
>   again.

So, in this you have to check whether **googleMap is null or not**. If null then you have to initialise it. All the map tiles has been rendered and all the labeling also completed as defined in docs.

**2. OnMapReadyCallback :**

> Once an instance of this interface is set on a MapFragment or MapView
>   object, the onMapReady(GoogleMap) method is triggered when the map is
>   ready to be used and provides a non-null instance of GoogleMap.

So, in this you don't have to check for the **null** in **onMapReady()** method.

Comment: Thanks @Clairvoyant. The "this will only be called once for `setOnMapLoadedCallback` is particularly true. One different I observed is, if I do quick scrolling on my recyclerview before the activity get loaded, the `setOnMapLoadedCallback` version might fail to move the camera of the the map, but `OnMapReadyCallback` works perfectly. I guess the quick scrolling before the activity load somehow have set MapAsLoaded before the camera move. So it didn't get to move on eventually. In short, my recommendation now is to use OnMapReadyCallback if the map is used as a ViewHolder in RecyclerView.

Comment: On my opinion **OnMapReadyCallback** is better also because we don't have to check **null** condition for the google map.

Answer (score 0):

Between calls of `OnMapReadyCallback` and `OnMapLoadedCallback` there is a gap. Within this gap map is already not null but it's parts could be not finally initialized. In very rare situations you can get `IllegalStateException` after executing some methods after `OnMapReadyCallback` and before `OnMapLoadedCallback`. For example moving map camera can cause it by `map.moveCamera` or `map.animateCamera`.

But on the other hand waiting of `OnMapLoadedCallback` is protracting your map initialisation and user can see this.
I've decided to use such approach

```
mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback()
         {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) 
            {
                try {
                    setUpMap();
                }
                catch (IllegalStateException e)
                {
                    map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapLoaded() {
                            setUpMap();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don`t get the IllegalStateException, all I see is com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception. Maybe they changed it.

Answer (score 0):

In Koltin its simpler:

```
                map.setOnMapLoadedCallback {
                   // your code here, sample update camera
                   map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding))
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

OnMapLoadedCallback is used for cycles such as custom photos in markers.

OnMapReadyCallback is for static markers.

Comment: Hans, please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).